# Command-line parameters in Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to include this

```
du -s *|awk '{ if ($1 > 3000) print }'
```

in a shell script, but I want to parameterize the 3000. However, since the `$1` is already being used, I'm not sure what to do. This was a total failure:

```
size=$1
du -s *|awk '{ if ($1 > $size) print }'
```

**How can I pass a parameter in place of 3000 in the first script above?**

Comment: `{if ($1 > $size) print}` is equivalent to `$1>size`

Comment: @ghostdog74, well this `size=$1; du -s *|awk '{ $1>size }' doesn't work... not sure what your comment means

Comment: i mean in awk, `{if ($1 > $size) print}` is the same as `$1>size`. see my answer for clearer picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit expansion, so:

```
du -s *|awk '{ if ($1 > '"$1"') print }'
```

Comment: this is a great answer. could you include why it's better/worse/same as `du -s *|awk '{ if ($1 > '$1') print }'`?

Comment: If the first argument contains a space (it *shouldn't*, but I prefer not to hope things go right) then omitting the double quotes will cause awk to not necessarily work as desired.

Answer (score 4):

when passing shell variables to awk, try to use the `-v` option of awk as much as possible. This will be "cleaner" than having quotes all around

```
size="$1"
du -s *| awk -v size="$size" '$1>size'
```

Comment: The quotes in size="$1" are unnecessary. Simple variable assignments (FOO=$BAR) don't need quotes.

Comment: its my habit sometimes. no harm putting it in anyways.

Answer (score 3):

```
size=$1
du -s *|awk '{ if ($1 > '$size') print }'
```

Comment: Be a little careful, as passing a parameter with a space in it will cause this to fail. This may of course be desirable.

Comment: But using your answer you can also just nix the $size and use $1 where you used $size. Anything wrong with that option?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `awk` variables on its command line:

```
du -s * | awk '{ if ($1 > threshold) print }' threshold=$1
```

Comment: only exception using this method is that `threshold` will not have value in BEGIN{} block.

Comment: @ghostdog74 what do you miss without the BEGIN{} block?